# PHP create new arrays based on the values of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple PHP multi-dimension array that I'm wanting to loop through, specifically the array with the name `License` and add all the `values` item that start with the same first word to its own array (with the key set to that word).

The idea is I'd end up with something similar to this:

```
[desktop] => Array(
    [0] => 1–3 users
    [1] => 4–6 users
    [2] => 7–10 users
)
[web] => Array(
    [0] => 10k views/month
    [1] => 25k views/month
    [2] => 50k views/month
)
[app] => Array(
    [0] => 5k downloads
    [1] => 5k–10k downloads
    [2] => 10k–25k downloads
)
```

This is an example of the array I'm working with `$product['options']`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6059896471689
            [product_id] => 4678842515593
            [name] => Class
            [position] => 1
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Regular
                    [1] => Oblique
                    [2] => Family
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6355533201545
            [product_id] => 4678842515593
            [name] => License
            [position] => 2
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Desktop 1–3 users
                    [1] => Desktop 4–6 users
                    [2] => Desktop 7–10 users
                    [3] => Desktop 11–15 users
                    [4] => Desktop 16–25 users
                    [5] => Desktop 25–50 users
                    [6] => Desktop 51–100 users
                    [7] => Desktop 101–150 users
                    [8] => Desktop 151–250 users
                    [9] => Desktop 251–400 users
                    [10] => Desktop 401–700 users
                    [11] => Desktop 701–1000 users
                    [12] => Desktop 1000+ users
                    [13] => Web 10k views/month
                    [14] => Web 25k views/month
                    [15] => Web 50k views/month
                    [16] => Web 100k views/month
                    [17] => Web 250k views/month
                    [18] => Web 500k views/month
                    [19] => Web 750k views/month
                    [20] => Web 1m+ views/month
                    [21] => App 5k downloads
                    [22] => App 5k–10k downloads
                    [23] => App 10k–25k downloads
                    [24] => App 25k–50k downloads
                    [25] => App 50–100k downloads
                    [26] => App 100k–250k downloads
                    [27] => App 250k–500k downloads
                    [28] => App 500k–1m downloads
                    [29] => App 1m+ downloads
                )

        )

)
```

And this is where I'm currently at:

```
foreach ($product['options'] as $option) {

    if ($option['name'] == 'Style') {
        $optionTitle = 'Select your fonts';
    } elseif ($option['name'] == 'License') {
        $optionTitle = 'Please select the type of license(s) you require';
    } else {
        $optionTitle = '';
    }

    $optionValues = array();

    foreach ($option['values'] as $value) {

        if ($option['name'] == 'License') {

            // 3 different arrays to be added to $optionValues (desktop, web, app) HOW?

            //substr(strstr($value, ' '), 1);

        } else {

            $optionValues[] = $value;

        }


    }

    if ($option['name'] == 'License') {
        $optionValues['desktop'] = ???;
        $optionValues['web'] = ???;
        $optionValues['app'] = ???;
    }

    $productOptions[] = array(
        'name' => $option['name'],
        'title' => $optionTitle,
        'values' => $optionValues
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the data split up as you want, you can just use `explode()` with a space, but limit it to 2 items.  The first is the type and the second is the range.  Then add the items to the `$optionValues` array using these values.

So something like ...

```
    if ($option['name'] == 'License') {
        list($type, $range) = explode(" ", $value, 2);
        $optionValues[$type][] = $range;
    } else {
```

You can also remove the following code...

```
if ($option['name'] == 'License') {
    $optionValues['desktop'] = ???;
    $optionValues['web'] = ???;
    $optionValues['app'] = ???;
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is great. I got it working but having to use the part you told me to remove, so this is ideal as it's more dynamic :)